# Каково происхождение слова «взбалмошный»?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Согласно словарю русского языка в 4 томах РАН Евгеньевой «Взбалмошный» значит:

> **ВЗБА́ЛМОШНЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -шен, -шна, -шно. Разг. Сумасбродный,
> неуравновешенный, с причудами. *Это был простой степной барин, довольно
> взбалмошный, крикун, --- грубый, но не злой.* Тургенев, Дворянское
> гнездо.

По поводу происхождения слова в Викисловаре, написано, что оно происходит от «балмошь».

> От сущ. балмошь «сумасбродство»...

По словарю Макса Фасмера «балмошь» состоит из двух частей «бал-» и «-мочь»:

> ба́лмошь ба́ломошь ж. "сумасбродство", ба́лмочь – то же. Вторая форма,
> вероятно, более старая; -ш- обобщен из формы ба́лмошный "сумасбродный,
> бестолковый". В этом случае бал- – то же, что и в балагу́р, баламу́т,
> в сложении с мочь...

Согласно тому же Фасмеру в словах «балагур» и «баламут»

> …Первая часть к бая́ть или *bolbol-: балабо́лить...

> …bala- — образование звукоподражательного характера...

Таким образом, получается, что первая часть «балмошь» «бал-» значит «речь».
Если вторую часть «-мочь» понимать как «быть в силах что-то делать», то получается «балмошь» — это способность говорить или болтать, а «взбалмошный» — это способной говорит или болтать.

Но это совершенно не соответствует словарному значению слова. Как же так получилось?

Хотя слово «болтать» действительно имеет негативную коннотацию, она не настолько негативна, чтоб говорить о том, кто болтает, как о человеке сумасбродном, неуравновешенном и с причудами.

Каково происхождение слова «взбалмошный»? Как сформировалось такое его значение?